# How to add WinForm User Control Into WPF so that I can reference it in the xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I am migrating part of a WinForms project into WPF.

I want to add an existing WinForms User Control into a WPF Form. The WinForm user control is called "TicketPrinter" and lives in the same project as the WPF form.

In my xaml I have this line:

```
xmlns:Printers="clr-namespace:Project.UserControls.Printers"
```

And then I use it in my xaml here:

```
        <WindowsFormsHost Height="430" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="468,12,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324">
            <Printers:TicketPrinter Printers:Name="ZapTicketPrinter">
            </Printers:TicketPrinter>
        </WindowsFormsHost> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I run the project the user control appears on the form as expected.

But when I go into the code behind xaml.cs file and try to access "ZapTicketPrinter" it is not available as a reference.

i.e.

I try using ZapTicketPrinter and it's not recognised.

I've also tried the following:

```
TicketPrinter ticketPrinter = this.FindName("ZapTicketPrinter") as TicketPrinter;
```

but get a null

What am I missing? 
How do I reference the name in my code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

provide x:Name instead of printer:name

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <Printers:TicketPrinter x:Name="ZapTicketPrinter"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

MSDN Sample

Using code behind
<s>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx</s>
[Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx)

Using xaml
<s>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx</s>
[Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF by Using XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try using following code:

```
private void LoadWFUserControl() 
{
    // Initialize a Host Control which allows hosting a windows form control on WPF. Ensure that the WindowsFormIntegration Reference is present.
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

    // Create an object of your User control.
    MyWebcam uc_webcam = new MyWebcam();

    // Assign MyWebcam control as the host control's child.
    host.Child = uc_webcam;

    // Add the interop host control to the Grid control's collection of child controls. Make sure to rename grid1 to appr
    this.grid1.Children.Add(host);
}
```

Comment: I do exactly this on a WPF UserControl, using the control's loaded event, and just using a simple WinForms button, nothing shows